# SQLite how to do normailzation?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, normalization

I'm relatively new to database programming and I've been given the task of creating one for my job on Android.  I've been able to create a simple one using some basic SQL statements.  However, being a total noob, I don't know much about the DB architecture so I shoved the contents of the spreadsheet into the database (literally a direct mapping).  I extracted the DB from my device to desktop and took a look in the SQLiteBrowser tool and I realized that there was going to be a problem with querying for data (see below). After doing some Googling, I stumbled across something called DB Normalization and I was wondering how it could be applied to this particular situation:

I have an Excel spreadsheet with the following columns:

```
Region Sku Language App1 App2 App3 App4 ...
  US   AAA    EN     x    x   
 CAN   BBB    EN     x         x
  FR   CCC    FR          x         x
 ...
```

It's basically data that will be used to determine what apps to hide on a device (based on an application's package name).  An "x" indicates that an App with a given Region, Sku, and Language will not be hidden, and a blank indicates that it will be.

I've read a few articles on the web and most have suggested going up to NF3 form, but for this set of data, I'm struggling to convert it into a NF1 form.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a new table for Apps Supported.  Make the Primary Key in the new table a Foreign key in the original table, in a one to many relationship.  Remove the APP1, App2, etc. fields from the original table.  Add a new record to the Apps Supported table for each app that a particular record in the first table supports.